# Python => IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed

Tags: python, scikit-image, imread

My code is here and IMG_HEIGHT, WIDTH  CHANNALS 128,128,3.

```
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids), total=len(train_ids)):
path = TRAIN_PATH + id_
img = imread(path + '/images/' + id_ + '.jpg')[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
img = resize(img, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True)
X_train[n] = img  # Fill empty X_train with values from img
mask = np.zeros((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)
for mask_file in next(os.walk(path + '/masks/'))[2]:
    mask_ = imread(path + '/masks/' + mask_file)
    mask_ = np.expand_dims(resize(mask_, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), mode='constant', preserve_range=True), axis=-1)
    mask = np.maximum(mask, mask_)
```

The error message is "IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
" . What should i do?? i dont know how fixed

Comment: Please provide complete error message

Comment: Please provide the library you use to read images (`imread` is a function in plenty of python library). A guess is that you have some gray-scale images in your dataset.

Comment: File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/kera-xray/segmentation/segunet2.py", line 36, in <module>
    img = imread(path + '/images/' + id_ + '.jpg')[:,:,:IMG_CHANNELS]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 2-dimensional, but 3 were indexed

Comment: this is the complete error message

Comment: And additional code

Comment: train_ids = next(os.walk(TRAIN_PATH))[1]
test_ids = next(os.walk(TEST_PATH))[1]

X_train = np.zeros((len(train_ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS), dtype=np.uint8)
Y_train = np.zeros((len(train_ids), IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1), dtype=np.bool)

Comment: import tensorflow as tf
import os
import random
import numpy as np

from tqdm import tqdm

from skimage.io import imread, imshow
from skimage.transform import resize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt